# Calculate the angle of rotation between two vectors relative to the first vector

Tags: rotation, vector, linear-algebra, angles

I'm trying to get the angle between two 2D vectors relative to the first vector input. Every method I've tried has given me a value between 0-180 degrees but doesn't tell me whether it was a clockwise or counter-clockwise rotation.

For example: If I hold my forward vector in a variable and then turn counter-clockwise 45 degrees and use that as my second forward vector, I'm looking for -45 or 315 degrees as the output, not 45.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
float AngleBetween(Vector2 a, Vector2 b) {
    // Get a vector rotated 90 degrees from a.
    Vector2 perpendicular = new Vector2(a.y, -a.x);

    // Compute a scaled projection of b onto the original and rotated version.
    float x = Vector2.Dot(a, b);
    float y = Vector2.Dot(perpendicular, b);

    // Treat these as a point in a coordinate system where a is the x axis,
    // and perpendicular is the y axis, and get the polar angle of that point.
    return Mathf.Atan2(y, x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution for unity (Maybe there is a better solution, but it works):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        var v1 = new Vector3(1, 1, 0);//45
        var v2 = new Vector3(1, 0, 0);//0

        Debug.Log(GetDegree(v1, v2));
        Debug.Log(GetDegree(v2, v1));
    }

    private float GetDegree(Vector3 from, Vector3 to)
    {
        var rot = Quaternion.FromToRotation(from, to);
        var angle = 0.0f;
        var axis = Vector3.zero;
        rot.ToAngleAxis(out angle, out axis);

        if (Vector3.forward == axis)
        {
            return angle;
        }
        else
        {
            return angle - 360f;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
-315
44.99999
```